# Automatically add Account Team Members to Sales Team on Opportunity using an Apex Batch

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

We have a requirement to copy Account team members to Sales team of related Opportunity. This should happen on a daily basis.. I am new to salesforce please help me in code to develop this.Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Have you seen http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22480/trigger-to-copy-account-team-to-opportunity ? It's slightly different but still should be a good baseline. What have you tried so far?